# extract some field from rest assured response

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have a ResponseBody object and it is like that :

```
"data": {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "georghe",
    "surname": "sue"
 }
```

Can i ignore id field because I want to compare it with  my json data and it does not contain id field.
I get data like that `response.getBody().path("data").toString()` but id is also coming.

I tried to map to my java class like that

```
response.getBody().path("data").as(Student.java)
```

but I cannot use as method with path.(In my Student class, I use @jsonIgnore annotation above id)

I tried 2 different style but they are not working.Do you have any idea?

Student class:

```
Student class{
 private String name;
 private String surname;

 //getter and setters

}.
```

Comment: I'm confused here - the title says "extract some field", but in the description you're talking about ignoring one field...also, what are you trying to compare with what again?

Comment: Actually I do not want to see id field in response.

Answer (score 1):

so if you want to ignore/avoid having Id in the response, @JsonIgnore is the correct approach, but make sure you're using the proper annotation:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore
```

the same happen to me some time ago and it was caused by importing the annotation from wrong library (net.minidev.json.annotate)

UPDATE: so if you want to extract the Student object from data element, you can do something like this:

```
final Student student = given()
    .header(YOUR_HEADER, YOUR_HEADER_VALUE)
.when()
    .get(YOUR_URL)
.then()
    .statusCode(200)
    .extract().jsonPath().getObject("data", Student.class)
```

Comment: I can use @JsonIgnore but how can i map json data.I use `response.getBody().path("data").as(Student.java)` but not working because I cannot as method with path method.I add my Student object

Comment: @hagi10 see my update above, hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mapstruct (https://mapstruct.org/) with the following composition:

@Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)

(documentation, section 3.2).